# Efficient Join queries - Can it be done using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, model-associations

I have 4 models, A, B, C and D

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B
  has_many :C, :through => :B
end  

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :A  
  has_many   :C
  has_many   :D, :through => :C
end  

class C < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :B
end    

class D < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :C
end
```

I have a very naive implementation which is very obvious ...

```
<% A.B.each do |b| %>
  <%= b.number %>
  <% b.C.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What's the best way to get All C for A? 
What's the best way get All D for A?

I want to get all 'C' using order_by clause with "created_at" value instead of iterating through B.

May be I'm missing some ActiveRecord magic?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Because of A's relation with C through B, I can also do A.C directly right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to make a couple changes.

1. `class C` needs an association to `D`

   ```
   class C < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :B
     has_one :D
   end
   ```
2. If you want to access `A`'s `D`'s, you need to specify this as well.

   ```
   class A < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :B
     has_many :C, :through => :B
     has_many :D, :through => :C
   end
   ```

Now, to access all of `A`'s `C`'s:

```
-> a = A.where(:id => 1).includes(:C).first
  A Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "as".* FROM "as" WHERE "as"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  B Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."a_id" IN (1)
  C Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "cs".* FROM "cs" WHERE "cs"."b_id" IN (1, 2)
 => #<A id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-10 04:28:42", updated_at: "2012-01-10 04:28:42"> 
-> a.C
 => [#<C id: 1, b_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:10", updated_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:10">, #<C id: 2, b_id: 1, created_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:11", updated_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:11">, #<C id: 3, b_id: 2, created_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:21", updated_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:21">, #<C id: 4, b_id: 2, created_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:21", updated_at: "2012-01-10 04:30:21">]
```

Notice how another query is not executed when you call `a.C`. This is because ActiveRecord knows you will want to access the found `A`'s `C`'s by the `include` call, and generates the minimum number of queries. Same goes for `D`'s:

```
-> a = A.where(:id => 1).includes(:D).first
  A Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "as".* FROM "as" WHERE "as"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  B Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "bs".* FROM "bs" WHERE "bs"."a_id" IN (1)
  C Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "cs".* FROM "cs" WHERE "cs"."b_id" IN (1, 2)
  D Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "ds".* FROM "ds" WHERE "ds"."c_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Say you wanted all `A`'s `D`'s but wanted `C`'s ordered:

```
A.where(:id => 1).includes(:C).order('cs.created_at DESC').includes(:D)
```

Note you can also set this as a default on the association:

> The `:order` option dictates the order in which associated objects will be received (in the syntax used by an SQL `ORDER BY` clause).
>
> ```
> class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :orders, :order => "date_confirmed DESC"
> end
> ```

Comment: @iWasRobbed Thanks! B has many smilies through a really sad guy. (Now I can't stop seeing them.)

Comment: Brandon Thanks. I'll try this, but I think having associations solves this problem.

Comment: You can access the child objects without using `includes`, but Rails will generate a lot of queries. You should use `includes` to avoid [the N+1 problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Comment: Brandon, This is indeed a better and faster solution. Thanks.